# Javascript - Adding new label and data to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

As I know, it is possible to push more data into an array. Fe, I have an array:

```
G = [12, 34, 5].
```

Right now, I can access the nth element like this:

```
G[n]
```

I'd now like to push new data in it with a label, so I want the array to look like

```
G = [12, 34, 5, label:567856, other: Infinity]
```

where I can get 567856 by calling

```
G["label"] //(or Infinity by calling G["other"]). How can I achieve this?
```

I've found

```
G[i].push({
    label:567856, 
    other: Infinity
})
```

but this way it adds it as a whole new element, and I'm only able to call G[4]["other"], instead of G["other"]. How can I add the element as I've described?

Thank you!

Comment: Arrays does not have labels, you need to use another datatype.

Comment: That is not possible. Probably you want to use JSON objects instead

Comment: Is it important to your needs treating this new labelled data as a **new** element? Couldn't it be just a property, and call like ``G["other"]``? In fact you could use a sort of prototype to handle this, but I'd suggest you to keep things simpler, and avoid spending too much effort on small things.

Comment: Hi @lte__, please let me know if my answer use full for you ( so i could update my answer..) ?

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Andriy's answer, you need to use Javascript Objects rather than arrays. An object can have indices with custom names. For example, given

```
var newObj = {"hello": "world", "value":1, "inf": Infinity}
```

you can do

```
newObj['hello'] // "world"
newObj['value'] // 1
```

The problem with

```
G[i].push({
    label:567856, 
    other: Infinity
})
```

is that you are pushing an object with 2 attributes, not pushing 2 objects, that's why you need to use `G[4]["other"]`

See running [JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/fc0o5583/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
G["other"] = "something";
```

With this you will keep the original array, and now have the attribute `other`, but it is not in `[12, 34, 5]`

Whit this one you can add an object to the array:

```
G.push({other: 123})
console.log(G);//[12, 34, 5, object]
console.log(G[3].other);//123
```

The problem with

```
G[i].push({
    label:567856, 
    other: Infinity
})
```

is that you are pushing an object with 2 attributes, not pushing 2 objects, that's why you need to use G[4]["other"]

Answer (score 0):

Arrays isn't designed to suit your case.

See Array element accessing flow from [ECMAScript 262, 5.1 15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property
>   names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array
>   index if and only if ToString([ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(P)) is equal to P and
>   ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2^32−1.

So you simply cannot access Array element by alphabetical name because that key won't be parsed to integer by **ToUint32**.

You can add [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) to array and store it's index after pushing into array ( [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) would return you size of your array):

```
var G = [1,3,4];
var labelIndex = G.push({'label': 123}) - 1;
console.log(G[labelIndex]["label"]);
```

Actually that's solution would suite case when you have two or more objects inside your array with same property.

**Suggestion below not recommended!**

However, you can use code below to define your `G` Array properties, but it's not value of property of item from your array, it's array property:

```
G.other = Infinity;
G.label = 567856;
// Access newly created properties
console.log(G["other"]);
console.log(G["label"]);
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: This does not add a new element in the array

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are a type of object.  As such, they can contain properties:

```
G.label = 567856;
G.other = Infinity;
```

The advantage of arrays over other objects is that their indexed elements are *ordered*.

If you'd like the fourth and fifth elements in the array to be `567856` and `Infinity` *and* you want to be able to refer to those values with `G.label` and `G.other`, you can do so as follows:

```
var G = [12, 34, 5];

G.push(G.label = 567856);     //same as G.label = 567856;  G.push(G.label);
G.push(G.other = Infinity);
```

You can still iterate through the array using a loop:

```js
var G = [12, 34, 5];

G.push(G.label = 567856);    
G.push(G.other = Infinity);

G.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val);  // 12 ... 34 ... 5 ... 567856 ... Infinity
});

console.log(G.label);  //567856
console.log(G.other);  //Infinity
```

Note that this *does* create duplicates.  If you change `G.label` or `G.other` afterwards, those changes will *not* be reflected in the fourth and fifth elements of the array.

However, you can overcome that by creating setters on `G.label` and `G.other` using [**Object.defineProperty()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
var G = [12, 34, 5];

G.push(G.label = 567856);
G.push(G.other = Infinity);

G.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // 12 ... 34 ... 5 ... 567856 ... Infinity
});

console.log(G.label); //567856
console.log(G.other); //Infinity

Object.defineProperty(G, 'label', {
  set: function(x) {
    this[3] = x;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(G, 'other', {
  set: function(x) {
    this[4] = x;
  }
})

G.label = 99999;
G.other = 11111;

G.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // 12 ... 34 ... 5 ... 99999 ... 11111
});
```